# BlogEngine.net Error in RecaptchaControl.cs

Tags: asp.net, .net, blogengine.net

I have been using BlogEngine.net for blogs on couple of my sites that have not been updated in a long time. The other day I visited my blog and found out that none of the posts load because of this error:

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

return Convert.ToInt32(settings.GetSingleValue("MaxLogEntries`"));
Source File: mywebsite\wwwroot\blog\App_Code\Extensions\Recaptcha\RecaptchaControl.cs    Line: 132
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction. I have not worked on .Net in a while and also because I did not modify any code I feel this might be a setting/data issue.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you run the code locally and debug it?

Comment: @Kevin Raffay I have not done that because I don’t even have access to Visual Studio anymore. I’m looking how I can use a different open source option. Just because no code has been changed I thought this might not be code related.

Comment: Any ideas which opensource IDE I can use?

Comment: Try VS Code, or VS 2017 Community

Comment: @KevinRaffay Thanks, I was able to troubleshoot with the Community edition.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone dealing with this issue, under

```
 App_Data\datastore\extensions\
```

look at Recaptcha.xml. For me it was showing empty. I don't even use this extension and could not find it in admin. I deleted this file and after that the extension showed up in admin under disabled extensions. So that fixed the issue for me. Hopefully this can help others